# Why the following code works, but if I add "fin.exceptions(ifstream::badbit | ifstream::failbit);" to make the second try/catch work, I get an error?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, ifstream, ofstream

My code:

```cpp
int main() {
    string path = "D:\\myFile.txt";
    Point pointOfIllusion(1, 2, 3);
    Point pointOfDesilusion(3, 2, 1);
    ofstream fout;
    
    fout.exceptions(ofstream::badbit | ofstream::failbit); **// everything is ok with this string**
    try {
        cout << "Trying to read the file\n";
        fout.open(path, ofstream::app); 
        cout << "The file has been successfully created and opened\n";
    }
    catch(const ofstream::failure& ex){
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
        cout << ex.code() << endl;
        perror ("Could not open the file");
        abort();
    }
    fout.write((char*)&pointOfIllusion, sizeof(Point));
    fout.write((char*)&pointOfDesilusion, sizeof(Point));

    fout.close();
    
    ifstream fin;
    fin.exceptions(ifstream::badbit | ifstream::failbit); **// If I put this, it causes an error, described below, but without this string the following try/catch doesn't work**
    try {
        cout << "Trying to read the file\n";
        fin.open(path);
        cout << "The file has been successfully opened\n";
    }
    catch (const ifstream::failure& ex) {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
        cout << ex.code() << endl;
        perror ("Could not open the file");
        abort();
    }
    
    Point tempPoint;
    size_t length = 0;
    while (fin.read((char*)&tempPoint, sizeof(Point))) { **// The debugger throws the exception when I add the string above in this place, however I do not modify it at all**
        length++;
    }

    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    
    Point* Points = new Point[length];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            fin.read((char*)&Points[i], sizeof(Point));
            Points[i].Print();
        }
        delete[] Points;
        
    fin.close();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error in the loop:

```cpp
while (fin.read((char*)&tempPoint, sizeof(Point))) {
    length++;
}
```

The error is the following:

```
An exception was raised at address 0x0000007FFECCC3CF19 in WorkWithFiles.exe: Microsoft C++: std::ios_base::failure exception at memory address 0x0000000059CBAFEF80.
An unhandled exception occurred at address 0x0000007FFECCCCC3CF19 in WorkWithFiles.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::ios_base::failure at memory address 0x00000059CBAFEF80.
```

Without this code:

`fin.exceptions(ifstream::badbit | ifstream::failbit);`

there is no such errors and the program works, however it doesn't catch exceptions when using second `try`/`catch` block (with `fin` object). Only that of `fout` works.

Could you tell me, please, what I'm doing wrong?

I tried to practice `try`/`catch` with `ifstream`/`ofstream` objects, while opening the file with correct and wrong addresses.

Comment: please show the code that reproduces the error not code that needs to be modified to reproduce the error. Also try to remove code that is not needed to reproduce the error. Read about [mcve].

Comment: there is `fout.exceptions(ofstream::badbit | ofstream::failbit);`  in your code. Is that the line you refer to in the title?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, thank you for your answer. I have 2 similar blocks in my code. One that you mean refers to the "fout" object. I use "fout" object to create a file ("D:\\myFile.txt") and write my data in it. But I also have a second, "fin" object, that I use to read the data from my file. There is no problem with fout.exceptions... string you mean, but If I add a similar string for "fin" object, i.e. "fin.exceptions(ifstream::badbit|ifstream::failbit);" I start getting the error I described above. As I see in the debugger, the error occurs in the while loop below, that I don't change.

Comment: the answer below explains the issue. I didnt spot that this while loop is outside of your try catch (this would be really simpler if you would show the code that does cause the error rather than explain how it has to be modified). If you throw an exception and you dont catch it your program terminates. And that line you add tells `fin` to throw an exception.

Comment: I also do not understand why the two lines where you write to `fout`, `fout.write((char*)&pointOfIllusion, sizeof(Point));` and the other, are not inside the try catch. Also there you tell the stream to throw an exception but at the same time you dont properly handle the possible exceptions.

Comment: @ 463035818_is_not_an_ai, sorry, I'm still a beginner in studying C++ and I'm not familiar with editing the questions on this platform. Thank you for your advice, I reduced my question a little bit. 
 @Sam-Varshavchik, thank you very much for explaining that! I guess, that is the answer!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I just wanted to try if the program opens the file and return the exception if it could not. But you're right, it would be better to put the writing of the objects in the try_catch section as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without
>
> fin.exceptions(ifstream::badbit | ifstream::failbit);

So, this happens when this line is left in place. This line tells your computer to throw an exception if any operation on `fin` fails (the differences between the two states are immaterial here).

```
while (fin.read((char*)&tempPoint, sizeof(Point))) {
```

This line tells your computer to keep calling `read()` until `fin` is no longer in a good state. However, according to The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming, which says "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do", a failed `read()` will end up throwing an exception. So that's why this line ends up throwing an exception: because that's what you told your computer to do, when `fin`'s status changes to a failed state. The fact that there's a loop that calls `read()`, until that happens, doesn't change that. The exception gets thrown by `fin` itself, as part of `read()`, it never returns and the exception gets thrown, so the `while` loop never has a change to check `fin`'s state.

Comment: As a general rule, throwing an exception on `failbit`, at least on an input file, is not a good idea, precisely because this is the standard notification that the input has finished. (Exceptions on `badbit` are fine, and `failbit` on output is probably good too.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, thank you! I have deleted "failbit" in the input file and it works without it.